# Cordova. Can not close the standard backbutton

Tags: cordova, addeventlistener, back-button

I'm trying to prevent the program from switching to the previous page. I simplified the code. I take a classic example from Visual Studio for the Cordova project. I call one file index.html, another index2.html. I put in the body links to one another. Adding code from the backbutton interception documentation. And I add an alert() to see the processing by the button. I never see the work of this alert and the standard return to the previous page always works. Help. What's wrong?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
<head>
    <title>Back Button Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        function onLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Register the event listener
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
        }

        // Handle the back button
        //
        function onBackKeyDown() {
            alert("+++++++++");
            window.location = "index.html";

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <a href="index2.html">Device is Ready</p></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will only work in index.html, index2.html should have a similar code.

Also to prevent the app from closing you should add a `preventDefault()` to the index.html code.

```
function onBackKeyDown(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not help. Nothing has changed. ((I don’t know what to do. ((

Comment: I understood. This did not work only in the debugger. On real device ok. Thanks.